# Getting files over HTTP in Node using promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, promise, es6-promise

I wrote this function that fetches a file from a URL, taking redirects into account:

```
const fetchFile = (url, successCallback, errorCallback) => {
  http.get(url).on('response', function(response) {
    var body = ''
    if((response.statusCode == 301) || (response.statusCode == 302)) {
      console.log('Redirection for ' + url + ' to ' + response.headers.location + ' caught...')
      fetchFile(response.headers.location, successCallback, errorCallback)
      return
    }
    response.on('data', function(chunk) {
      body += chunk
    })
    response.on('end', function() {
      console.log('Completed!')
      successCallback(body)
    })
  })
}
```

This code seems to work correctly, and now I am trying to rewrite it to use promises without any external modules, but I'm not making much headway. I came up with this code:

```
const fetchFileProm = function(url) {
  console.log('In fetchFileProm()');
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log('In Promise function body')
    var req = http.get(url, (response) => {
      console.log('In Response handler func body');
      var body = ''
      if((response.statusCode == 301) || (response.statusCode == 302)) {
        console.log('Redirection for ' + url + ' to ' + response.headers.location + ' caught...')
        return fetchFileProm(response.headers.location)
      }
      response.on('data', (fragment) => { body += fragment })
      response.on('end', () => resolve(body) )
    })
    req.on('error', function(err) {
      reject(err)
    })
  })
}
```

When I run this, I get the `In Promise function body` message but nothing further than that. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `return fetchFileProm(response.headers.location)` needs to be `fetchFileProm(response.headers.location).then(resolve, reject)`

Comment: Node now has full support for [async/await](https://hackernoon.com/6-reasons-why-javascripts-async-await-blows-promises-away-tutorial-c7ec10518dd9), you should give that a go instead of Promises. Just saying

Comment: @Btz Look at the answer I posted, it's more thorough (the edits you made to the code in your question are insufficient)

Comment: @JeremyThille In order to use *async-await*, the `http.get()` operation would have to be 'promisified' anyway

Answer (score 0):

When you're in an asynchronous operation, a regular `return` doesn't work so when you're doing `return fetchFileProm(response.headers.location)`, nothing takes care of that return and there's nothing that will ever resolve your promise.

What you need to do is to recursively pass the callbacks to the next asynchronous operation:

```
      ...
      var req = http.get(url, (response) => {
        console.log('In Response handler func body');
        var body = ''
        if((response.statusCode == 301) || (response.statusCode == 302)) {
          console.log('Redirection for ' + url + ' to ' + response.headers.location + ' caught...')
          fetchFileProm(response.headers.location).then(resolve, reject);
        } else {
          response.on('data', (fragment) => { body += fragment })
          response.on('end', () => resolve(body) )
        }
      })
      ...
```

Comment: Unfortunately this fix doesn't solve the problem. I still get no further than the `In Promise function body` message.

Comment: @Btz If you don't even get the `In Response handler func body` then your first problem is with your `http.get()` call. Even if you get that sorted out, the modifications I suggested will still be necessary for redirects to work.

Comment: Sure, point taken. I just can't figure out what needs to be fixed for the http.get(). The callback-based version works fine.

Comment: @Btz Yeah, I can't see what's wrong with it either I'm afraid

Comment: Right, I made more experiments. If the url is for a non-redirected file, everything actually works fine. But if the url gets redirected, then for some reason it succeeds immediately with the redirection message ("You are being redirected to http://example.com/randomUrl") as the received data. So, like you suggested, the problem is in the structure of the call and in the way redirections are handled.